# pyqtgraph change color of node and its edges on click

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm working with `pyqtgraph` to create an interactive network of nodes and edges (initially from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791395/pyqtgraph-get-text-of-node-and-change-color-on-mouseclick) question, all code needed comes from [here](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph)). I'm trying to change the color of a node and its neighbors (edges and other nodes it is connected to) when clicking on that node. The code below shows how to get the node which was clicked as well as its edges and other nodes it is connected to. Now, I don't understand how one can change the color of specific pyqtgraph scatterplot items.

In the code below, I can change the color of all nodes of the graph with `scatter.setPen()`, but applying it to e.g. only the node I clicked on (`pts[0].setPen()`) does not work. Can anyone please tell me how to change the color of explicitly defined nodes and edges?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**Edit**:

After the very helpful hints from kesumu and the code snippets found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyqtgraph/pTrem1RCKSw) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyqtgraph/dqw_Lip8rNk), I finally got it working.

**Code**:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Simple example of subclassing GraphItem.
"""

# https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyqtgraph/pTrem1RCKSw
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867980/pyqtgraph-select-2d-region-of-graph-as-threshold-to-redraw-the-graph
# https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyqtgraph/pTrem1RCKSw
# https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyqtgraph/dqw_Lip8rNk

import initExample ## Add path to library (just for examples; you do not need this)

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
from pyqtgraph.Point import Point
import numpy as np


def MultiSelect(newLines, mypoint_index_all, mypoint_edges, mypoints_all_edges, allpoints_neighbornodes, symbolBrushs):
    mypoint_neighbornodes = list(set([e for tup in mypoint_edges for e in tup]))
    allpoints_neighbornodes.append(mypoint_neighbornodes)

    for myp_index in mypoint_index_all:
        symbolBrushs[myp_index] = pg.mkBrush(color=(255, 0, 0))
        for allmy_neighbornodes in allpoints_neighbornodes:
            for all_node in allmy_neighbornodes:
                symbolBrushs[all_node] = pg.mkBrush(color=(255, 0, 0))
            for myp_eges in mypoints_all_edges:
                for i in range(len(myp_eges)):
                    for j in range(len(adj)):
                        if np.array_equal(adj[j], myp_eges[i]):
                            break
                    index = j
                    newLines.itemset(index, (255, 0, 0, 255, 1))

    return newLines, symbolBrushs


class MyViewBox(pg.ViewBox):
    def mouseDragEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            ev.ignore()
        else:
            pg.ViewBox.mouseDragEvent(self, ev)

        ev.accept()
        pos = ev.pos()
        self.dragPoint = None
        if ev.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            if ev.isFinish():
                self.rbScaleBox.hide()
                self.ax = QtCore.QRectF(Point(ev.buttonDownPos(ev.button())), Point(pos))
                self.ax = self.childGroup.mapRectFromParent(self.ax)
                self.Coords =  self.ax.getCoords()
                self.getPointsInRect()
            else:
                self.updateScaleBox(ev.buttonDownPos(), ev.pos())

    def getPointsInRect(self):
        # Get the data from the Graphicsitem that are within scaleBox rectangle
        data = viewbx.allChildren()[2].data.tolist()
        rectangle_coordinates = self.Coords
        graph_nodes_x_coords = viewbx.allChildren()[2].getData()[0]
        graph_nodes_y_coords = viewbx.allChildren()[2].getData()[1]
        graph_nodes = zip(graph_nodes_x_coords, graph_nodes_y_coords)

        rect_x1 = rectangle_coordinates[0]
        rect_y1 = rectangle_coordinates[1]
        rect_x2 = rectangle_coordinates[2]
        rect_y2 = rectangle_coordinates[3]

        points_in_rect_list = []
        for tup in graph_nodes:
            point_x = tup[0]
            point_y = tup[1]
            if rect_x1 <= point_x <= rect_x2 and rect_y1 <= point_y <= rect_y2:
                points_in_rect_list.append(tup)

        self.changePointsColors(points_in_rect_list, data, graph_nodes_x_coords, graph_nodes_y_coords)

    def changePointsColors(self, pointslist, data, graph_nodes_x_coords, graph_nodes_y_coords):
        data_x = [tup[0] for tup in pointslist]
        data_y = [tup[1] for tup in pointslist]
        newPos = np.vstack([graph_nodes_x_coords, graph_nodes_y_coords]).transpose()
        newLines = lines.copy()
        symbolBrushs = [None] * len(data)

        if QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:  # check if ctrl key is pressed
            self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_indx = g.symbolBrushs_allpoints_indx
            self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_neighbornodes = g.symbolBrushs_allpoints_neighbornodes
            self.mypoint_edges_allpoints = g.mypoint_edges_allpoints

        else:
            self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_indx = []
            self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_neighbornodes = []
            self.mypoint_edges_allpoints = []

        for x, y in zip(data_x, data_y):
            for tup in data:
                if x == tup[0] and y == tup[1]:
                    mypoint_indx = data.index(tup)
                    mypoint_edges = [tup for tup in g.data['adj'] if mypoint_indx in tup]

                    self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_indx.append(mypoint_indx)
                    self.mypoint_edges_allpoints.append(mypoint_edges)

                    mypoint_neighbornodes = list(set([e for tup in mypoint_edges for e in tup]))
                    self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_neighbornodes.append(mypoint_neighbornodes)

        newLines, symbolBrushs = MultiSelect(newLines=newLines, mypoint_index_all=self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_indx,
                               mypoint_edges=mypoint_edges, mypoints_all_edges=self.mypoint_edges_allpoints,
                               allpoints_neighbornodes=self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_neighbornodes, symbolBrushs=symbolBrushs)

        g.setData(pos=newPos, adj=adj, pen=newLines, size=1, symbol=symbols, pxMode=False, text=texts,
              symbolBrush=symbolBrushs)

        g.updateGraph()


class Graph(pg.GraphItem):
    def __init__(self):
        self.textItems = []
        pg.GraphItem.__init__(self)
        self.scatter.sigClicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_indx = []
        self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_neighbornodes = []
        self.mypoint_edges_allpoints = []

    def setData(self, **kwds):
        self.text = kwds.pop('text', [])
        self.data = kwds
        if 'pos' in self.data:
            npts = self.data['pos'].shape[0]
            self.data['data'] = np.empty(npts, dtype=[('index', int)])
            self.data['data']['index'] = np.arange(npts)
        self.setTexts(self.text)
        self.updateGraph()

    def setTexts(self, text):
        for i in self.textItems:
            i.scene().removeItem(i)
        self.textItems = []
        for t in text:
            item = pg.TextItem(t)
            self.textItems.append(item)
            item.setParentItem(self)

    def updateGraph(self):
        pg.GraphItem.setData(self, **self.data)
        for i,item in enumerate(self.textItems):
            item.setPos(*self.data['pos'][i])

    def mouseDragEvent(self, ev):
        ev.accept()
        pos = ev.pos()

        if ev.isStart():
            # We are already one step into the drag.
            # Find the point(s) at the mouse cursor when the button was first
            # pressed:
            pos = ev.buttonDownPos()
            pts = self.scatter.pointsAt(pos)
            if len(pts) == 0:
                ev.ignore()
                return
            self.dragPoint = pts[0]
            ind = pts[0].data()[0]
            self.dragOffset = self.data['pos'][ind] - pos
        if ev.isFinish():
            self.dragPoint = None
            return
        else:
            if self.dragPoint is None:
                ev.ignore()
                return

        ind = self.dragPoint.data()[0]
        self.data['pos'][ind] = ev.pos() + self.dragOffset
        self.updateGraph()
        ev.accept()

    def clicked(self, scatter, pts):
        # print(self)
        data_list = scatter.data.tolist()
        mypoint = [tup for tup in data_list if pts[0] in tup][0]
        mypoint_index = data_list.index(mypoint)
        mypoint_edges = [tup for tup in self.data['adj'] if mypoint_index in tup]
        mypoint_neighbornodes = list(set([e for tup in mypoint_edges for e in tup]))

        data = scatter.getData()
        newPos = np.vstack([data[0], data[1]]).transpose()
        newLines = lines.copy()
        symbolBrushs = [None] * len(data[0])

        if QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:  # check if ctrl key is pressed
            self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_indx.append(mypoint_index)
            self.mypoint_edges_allpoints.append(mypoint_edges)
            self.mypoint_neighbornodes = list(set([e for tup in mypoint_edges for e in tup]))
            self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_neighbornodes.append(mypoint_neighbornodes)

            newLines, symbolBrushs = MultiSelect(newLines=newLines, mypoint_index_all=self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_indx,
                                     mypoint_edges=mypoint_edges, mypoints_all_edges=self.mypoint_edges_allpoints,
                                     allpoints_neighbornodes=self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_neighbornodes,
                                     symbolBrushs=symbolBrushs)

        else:
            self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_indx = []
            self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_neighbornodes = []
            self.mypoint_edges_allpoints = []

            self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_indx.append(mypoint_index)
            self.mypoint_edges_allpoints.append(mypoint_edges)
            self.mypoint_neighbornodes = list(set([e for tup in mypoint_edges for e in tup]))
            self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_neighbornodes.append(mypoint_neighbornodes)
            print(self.symbolBrushs_allpoints_indx)

            symbolBrushs[mypoint_index] = pg.mkBrush(color=(255, 0, 0))
            for neighbornode in mypoint_neighbornodes:
                symbolBrushs[neighbornode] = pg.mkBrush(color=(255, 0, 0))
            for i in range(len(mypoint_edges)):
                for j in range(len(adj)):
                    if np.array_equal(adj[j], mypoint_edges[i]):
                        break
                index = j
                newLines.itemset(index, (255, 0, 0, 255, 1))

        g.setData(pos=newPos, adj=adj, pen=newLines, size=1, symbol=symbols, pxMode=False, text=texts,
                  symbolBrush=symbolBrushs)

        self.updateGraph()


# Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
w = pg.GraphicsWindow()
w.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: CustomGraphItem')
viewbx = MyViewBox()
w.addItem(viewbx)
viewbx.setAspectLocked()

g = Graph()
viewbx.addItem(g)

# Define positions of nodes
pos = np.array([
    [0,0],
    [10,0],
    [0,10],
    [10,10],
    [5,5],
    [15,5]
    ], dtype=float)

# Define the set of connections in the graph
adj = np.array([
    [0,1],
    [1,3],
    [3,2],
    [2,0],
    [1,5],
    [3,5],
    ])

# Define the symbol to use for each node (this is optional)
symbols = ['o','o','o','o','o','o']

# Define the line style for each connection (this is optional)
lines = np.array([
    (255,255,255,255,1),
    (255,255,255,255,2),
    (255,255,255,255,3),
    (255,255,255,255,2),
    (255,255,255,255,1),
    (255,255,255,255,4),
    ], dtype=[('red',np.ubyte),('green',np.ubyte),('blue',np.ubyte),('alpha',np.ubyte),('width',float)])

# Define text to show next to each symbol
texts = ["Point %d" % i for i in range(6)]

# Update the graph
g.setData(pos=pos, adj=adj, pen=lines, size=1, symbol=symbols, pxMode=False, text=texts)


# Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyqtgraph get text of node and change color on MouseClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791395/pyqtgraph-get-text-of-node-and-change-color-on-mouseclick)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate. I asked the above question as well, but changed now the title of it to clarify that it does not go as far as this question here goes.

Comment: You should improve your questions, have the same title and for me is a duplicate, try to take the right time to ask, that is a show of respect for the community. Keep in mind that pyqtgraph is used in few questions and we are very few that answer these questions.

Comment: Ok, I see, you are right. I unfortunately just changed the title of the previous question. I will change it back to how it was initially. Apologies for that, I thought it will be clearer to break those two questions apart. I have a deep respect for the community.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why `scatter.setPen(pens)` or `scatter.setBrush(brushes)` is not working. 
As an alternative, you can use `g.setData` like this:

```
def clicked(self, scatter, pts):
    data_list = scatter.data.tolist()
    mypoint = [tup for tup in data_list if pts[0] in tup][0]
    mypoint_index = data_list.index(mypoint)
    mypoint_edges = [tup for tup in self.data['adj'] if mypoint_index in tup]

    data = scatter.getData()
    newPos = np.vstack([data[0],data[1]]).transpose()
    newLines = lines.copy()
    symbolBrushs = [None] * len(data[0])
    symbolBrushs[mypoint_index] = pg.mkBrush(color=(255, 0, 0))
    for i in range(len(mypoint_edges)):
        for j in range(len(adj)):
            if np.array_equal(adj[j], mypoint_edges[i]):
                break
        index = j
        newLines.itemset(index, (255,0,0,255,1))
    g.setData(pos=newPos, adj=adj, pen=newLines, size=1, symbol=symbols, pxMode=False, text=texts, symbolBrush=symbolBrushs)

    self.updateGraph()
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: kesumu, thank you so much for your help! I made some minor addition to also color the neighbor nodes in red (see edit). Now, when I change the MouseMode (via menue by right-clicking) to 1 button, I can use the rectangle selection to zoom in to a specific area of the graph. Do you maybe know how I can change this behavior to, instead of zoomin in, allow the user to select multiple nodes at once? Multiple selection by pressing ctrl or shift key does not work. Maybe you know more?

Comment: You are welcome, dliv. It seems when you pressed and move your mouse, it will trigger `Graph.mouseDragEvent(self, ev)`, maybe you can modify this function to record the start and end of your moving to achieve multiple selecting. Or as an easier way, you can modify `Graph.clicked(self, scatter, pts)`, make additional detection for ctrl or shift key, and then add new clicked nodes to be red instead of canceling old red nodes.

Comment: keusmu, again, thank you for your help. I really do appreciate it. Ok, I had a shot at modifying `Graph.mouseDragEvent(self, ev)` and `Graph.clicked(self, scatter, pts`), but neither of them is working... :( I edited my question with what I've tried. Apologies if this should be straightforward, I'm still quite new to pyqtgraph.